# Trying to make wordle but having problems with the letter check

Tags: python, random, wordle-game

The propolem is Exception has occurred: IndexError
string index out of range. this happens in line 46
and to have lots of word option made a list with 5 letter words
i think the propolem is with the fact i origonial made it for number instead of leaters
The propolem is Exception has occurred: IndexError
string index out of range. this happens in line 46
and to have lots of word option made a list with 5 letter words
i think the propolem is with the fact i origonial made it for number instead of leaters

```
##
# wordel
 
# Print the welcome message.
print("Welcome to wordel!")
print("You will guess the final word.")
 
##
# random words
# using randint()
import random

# open file
with open(r"C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\wordel list.txt") as file:
    data = file.read()
    words = data.split()
    
    # Generating a random number for word position
    final_word = random.randint(0, len(words)-1)
    print("Position:", final_word)
    print("Word at position:", words[final_word])
# Set an empty final_word.
final_word = ""
password_is_valid = False
```

```
# Print 100 empty lines.
for i in range(0, 100):
    print()

# Keep track of the player's progress.
counter = 0                # The current turn number.
guessed_correctly = False  # Whether Player 2 has guessed correctly.
all_guess_symbols = ""      # All of the symbols.

# Loop 10 times, maximum
while counter < 10:
    # Ask for player 2's guess.
    guess_number = counter + 1
    guess = input("guess the final_word: ")

    # Only consider the guess if it is four digits long.
    if len(guess) == 5:
        # Create a string with the symbols for the current guess.
        current_guess_symbols = ""
        for i in range(0, 5):
            if guess[0] == final_word[0]:
                current_guess_symbols = current_guess_symbols + ""
            else:
                current_guess_symbols = current_guess_symbols + ""
        
        # Add the current guess' shapes to the whole game's shapes.
        all_guess_symbols = all_guess_symbols + current_guess_symbols + "\n"
        print(current_guess_symbols)
 
        # If the guess symbols are all green circles, Player 2 won.
        # Set the
        if current_guess_symbols == "":
            # Set the counter to 10 to immediately end the game loop.
            counter = 10
            guessed_correctly = True
        else:
            # Continue to the next guess.
            counter = counter + 1
    else:
        # Print an error message if the guess is too short.
        print("Sorry, your guess is too short. Enter a 5 digit final_word.")
 
# Print all guess symbols at the end of the game.
print()
print(all_guess_symbols)
print()
 
# Print the ending message.
if guessed_correctly == True:
    print("Congratulations, you guessed the final_word!")
else:
    print("Sorry, you did not guess in time.")
    print("The final_word was: " + final_word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting IndexError at this line:

```
if guess[0] == final_word[0]:
```

This is most likely because either `guess` or `final_word` is an empty string. You have applied no input validation to the user's guess, so that could easily become an empty string. (also that line should probably be `if guess[i] == final_word[i]:`).
However with the code as you've written, `final_word` is guaranteed to be an empty string.

Your code at lines 14-21 does successfully read a word from the specified file (assuming your file is non-empty), but then at line 23 you have:

```
# Set an empty final_word.
final_word = ""
```

Which resets the variable to the empty string.

Comment: hi after getting rid of the final_word = "", there is a new error of 'int' object is not subscriptable in line 45

Comment: @drammaone2tree, you should examine your code and see where the final_word variable is set and make sure it is what you expect